# Disable dialog for host to accept connection in WiFiP2PManager

Tags: java, android, p2p, wifi-direct

I'm just looking at the WiFiP2PManager in Android. It appears that if I host a service and a user connects, then the host has to approve the connection. However, I do not want this as in my application the host will acknowledge this when they start hosting.

Is there anyway to do that, and if I can't do that in anyway at all, is there a way of telling the system that the user tapped 'Yes'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this though from Android 4.2.2 it is possible to remember previous groups.

Look at this issue(it deals with this exact problem):https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30880